# BigBlueButton Customization

Tags: meteor, bigbluebutton

I am planning to customize  Big Blue Button  HTML 5 client layout.
but, i  know that it is very difficult.

To customize some  file,  I  tried to find  imports  directory of  HTML 5 client.

but, I  didn't find it for a few days.
I found other  all directories.
only,  I didn't find imports directory.

i am very terrible with it.
so, I  hoped your help about this.
really, where exists this directory?

Comment: how are you importing/using bigbluebutton in meteor?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. I haven't look at it, but it's not mandatory to use `/imports` in a Meteor project, it is merely a convention. Looking at the docs, I see there is a meteor project that you can download and run, that should be pretty straight forward.

Looking at this folder: `https://github.com/bigbluebutton/bigbluebutton/tree/develop/bigbluebutton-html5`

There is indeed a `imports` folder there. Maybe you are looking in the wrong place?